# Dynamic styling of FusionTableLayer with Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I've run in some trouble styling Fusion Layer and I would really 
 appreciate your help. 
 I add a layer with default styling defined as

```
layer.set('styles', [{ 
                 polygonOptions: { 
                         fillColor: '#FFFFFF', 
                         fillOpacity: 1, 
                         strokeColor: '#000000', 
                         strokeWeight: 1 
                 } 
         }]);
```

This works fine. Then a click listener is set for this layer. The 
 story goes like this: user clicks a feature on the map. If its 
 property equals to the value given (e. g. in the form), I want this 
 feature to get different fillColor than the rest.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(okresy,'click', function(ev) { 
                 nazev = ev.row.NAZEV.value; 
                         layer.set("styles", [{ 
                                 polygonOptions: { 
                                         fillColor: '#FFFFFF', 
                                         fillOpacity: 1, 
                                         strokeColor: '#000000', 
                                         strokeWeight: 1 
                                 }, 
                                 where: "'NAZEV' = '"+nazev+"'", 
                                 polygonOptions : { 
                                         fillColor : '#008C00', 
                                         fillOpacity : 1, 
                                         strokeColor : '#000000', 
                                         strokeWeight : 1 
                                 } 
                         }]); 

});
```

So what I do is setting color #008C00 to the feature clicked and to 
 every other feature I assign the same style as in the beginning. 
 However, whatever I do, I can't make it work. The rest of the features 
 gets that default half-transparent red color when some feature is 
 clicked. Am I missing something? Opera Dragonfly doesn't report any code mistakes, so I suppose the syntax is ok.

Comment: Do you have anywhere your whole page is hosted so we can give it a try and debug? Or maybe you could put up a jsFiddle?

Comment: I uploaded the code to http://jsfiddle.net/9Rayd/3/. Hope it works, never used it before.

Answer (score 2):

Ha, problem solved! I actually needed something more like this:

```
okresy.set("styles", [{ 
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#FFFFFF', 
            fillOpacity: 1, 
            strokeColor: '#000000', 
            strokeWeight: 1 }}, 
        {where: "'NAZEV' = '"+nazev+"'", 
         polygonOptions : {
            fillColor : '#008C00', 
            fillOpacity : 1, 
            strokeColor : '#000000', 
            strokeWeight : 1 
         }} 
]);
```

Debugger didn't report any error though, that's what was confusing me.